# Which number is closer

Tags: delphi

How can i find out which number is closer?  say my value is  "1"  and i have two var,  A:= 1.6 and b:=1.001

currently looking at a few numbers and taking a 0.1% +/- difference and a +/- 0.6  difference.. i just need to see which answer is closer to the starting value.. code so far..

Also nothing to big, the code is just to stop me from doing them all manually :D

```
    procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
winlimit,test6high,test6low,test6,test1high,test1low,test1,value: double;
begin
 value := 1.0;
 while value < 1048567 do
  begin
     test6high := value + 0.6 ;
     test6low := value - 0.6 ;

     test1high := (-0.1 * value)/100;
     test1high := value - test1high;

     test1low := (0.1 * value)/100;
     test1low := value - test1low;

     memo1.Lines.Add('value is '+floattostr(value)+': 1% High:'+floattostr(Test1high)+' 1% Low:'+floattostr(Test1low));
     memo1.Lines.Add('value is '+floattostr(value)+': 0.6 +/- '+floattostr(Test6high)+' 0.6 Low:'+floattostr(Test6low));
     memo1.Lines.Add(' ');
     value := value*2;
 end
end;
```

Comment: Do you mean `IfThen(abs(A-B)<abs(A-C), B, C)`?

Comment: ill try it and tell ya..but not sure how to try that..Where i add the text to memo lines, I just wanted to show the value that is closer to the orginal value, instead of showing both

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you mean a function like this:

```
function ClosestTo(const Target, Value1, Value2: Double): Double;
begin
  if abs(Target-Value1)<abs(Target-Value2) then
    Result := Value1
  else
    Result := Value2;
end;
```

If you use `IfThen` from the `Math` unit you can write it more concisely:

```
function ClosestTo(const Target, Value1, Value2: Double): Double;
begin
  Result := IfThen(abs(Target-Value1)<abs(Target-Value2), Value1, Value2);
end;
```

Comment: Ahh perfect,  I recommend using the math unit.. that IfThen is nice, never knew that was there..  thanks

Comment: @GelnMorse in modern languages it is part of standard if-then-else statement. But since Delphi is deeply rooted in 1973's Pascal Report and have expression-mode for IF and CASE, Borland chosen to overcome this with set of RTL functions for most common types.